# I need advice on how to get out of default on college student loans

Tags: united-states, student-loan, debt-reduction, social-security

Well, this is not very specific, but I need advice on how to get out of default on college student loans. Right now I am on Social Security, Medicaid and food stamps.  It made things more difficult since I would lose them before making enough to support myself and pay them but I am thankful for them. So if you know of any special grants or the like, please let me know. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You mean you have defaulted on your loans and it is affecting your credit report?  You can start paying them back to get on track, but it will take years before it comes of of your credit report.  You can't unring a bell.

Comment: Are you disabled or unable to work? What is your degree in?

Comment: Are these federal student loans or private student loans?

Comment: @HartCO What would be the options between the two?

Comment: I was about to ask what @DStanley did and you haven't responded, so it would be difficult to help you. Additionally, you have extensive options available to you to avoid default in situation of health or money, so why didn't you contact someone to get them activated? Looks like you ignored it and when it blew back on you, suddenly you want to resolve it; but consider that now you are going to have a near impossible time fixing something that would have been as easy a a single page form to be submitted to your loan managers. Nowadays, an email actually.

Answer (score 2):

Student loans are not easily discharged in bankruptcy.  The only ways (short of dying) to "get out" of them is if you become disabled and can't work.  There are forgiveness programs if you work in underserved areas like teaching in lower-income areas or working in public service/military.  There is nothing else that will make them just "go away".

If you are totally and permanently unable to work, then you can apply for forgiveness through a [disability discharge](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/forgiveness-cancellation/disability-discharge).

Other than that, you're probably looking at a long road to pay these off.  Start by finding work that gets you off of government aid (you're right, welfare won't pay for your needs and student loans).

I wish there were better options.  Well, in reality I wish that more people thought about the risks of student loans before going thousands of dollars into debt without an income or collateral to back it up, but that is the nature of student debt today.

Comment: Side note: forgiveness only works on your Federal loans. Not on private loans, which a lot of people also have.

Comment: A slight correction. Private student loans and some loans with a cosigner are not dischargeable upon death.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have learned this through the years of trying to find out how to take care of them right. Mine are defaulted unfortunately and most forgiveness programs are for delinquent loans not default. I do not like it but as I said if I tried to work I could lose the benefits that I have now. I did get a partial forgiveness but it did not cover the loans I already had in earlier years.